# XML Schema format file: pain.008.002.02

Tags: xsd, iso, financial, banking

Has anyone ever run across pain.008.002.02 format? It is an ISO standard used in Germany used for direct debit transactions. The problem I have is that although I had found documentation that talks about it, I did not actually find the XML Schema (pain.008.002.02.xsd) for it, which would be very useful in generating java bindings. Otherwise I will need to do this manually, which is simply hell. Does anyone know where I could find it? Its not on the ISO page with all the other formats. If the file has to be bought (I run in to places which could point to this), such information would also be very useful.

Comment: As for reference to others, here http://www.iso20022.org/message_archive.page you can download many of pain.xxx.xxx.xx.xsd files. Unfortunately, not pain.008.002.02.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would download the [SEPA Explorer](http://www.sepa-explorer.net), install it and then look in the install folder (SEPAExplorerV2\XSDFiles) for what you need (pain.008.002.02.xsd is in there).

Already generated Java bindings for the XSD you're looking for are in the Open Banking Tools (LGPL) [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/obantoo/files/).

Comment: Any solution for non-Windows users?

Answer (score 9):

After hours and hours of searching, I found it in the ebics archive:
http://www.ebics.de/index.php?id=77 at the bottom of the page "Anlage3_Archiv_V2_5.zip"

Ebics is the official "Electronic Banking Internet Communication Standard" from the Deutsche Kreditwirtschaft.

Comment: Here's another link https://github.com/digitick/php-sepa-xml/blob/master/tests/pain.008.002.02.xsd